# Stick the values for specific ids based on the date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df and I want to stick the values of each id in one row based on its values. For example, in the follwing df I want to see the values:
of day "2019-01-01" and " 2019-01-02" and "2019-01-03" for id 1 and same for id 2. I am using the following code, however,   it put the values with this order "val1    val10   val11   val12   val2    val3    val4    val5"

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['id'] = [1, 1, 2,2, 3, 3, 3]
df['date'] = ['2019-01-01', '2019-01-03', '2019-01-01','2019-01-02', '2019-01-01',   '2019-01-02','2019-01-03']
df['val1']  = [10, 100, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]
df['val2']  = [30, 30, -20, -30, -40,-50, -60 ]
df['val3']  = [50, 10, 120, 300, 140, 150, 160]

df['val4']  = [10, 100, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]
df['val5']  = [30, 30, -20, -30, -40,-50, -60 ]
df['val6']  = [50, 10, 120, 300, 140, 150, 160]

df['val7']  = [10, 100, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]
df['val8']  = [30, 30, -20, -30, -40,-50, -60 ]
df['val9']  = [50, 10, 120, 300, 140, 150, 160]
df['val10']  = [10, 100, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]
df['val11']  = [30, 30, -20, -30, -40,-50, -60 ]
df['val12']  = [50, 10, 120, 300, 140, 150, 160]
```

Here is the code I use and here is the output which is wrong. I also want to replace the missing date with the same day before or after it.

```
val_cols = df.filter(like='val').columns

df_s = (df.pivot('id', 'date', val_cols).groupby(level=0, axis=1).apply(lambda x:x.ffill(axis=1).bfill(axis=1)).sort_index(axis=1, level=1))
```

[image]

Can you please help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking something like the following. I wrote the code for 1 `val`. You can add multiple `val`.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'id': np.repeat(range(1, 6), 5),
                   'date': np.repeat(pd.date_range('2019-01-01', '2019-05-01', freq='M'), 5),
                   'val': np.random.randint(10, size=25)})
                   
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

The above answer also works for me. However, I finally used another simple method to solve that. The reason which this happens, is related to the name of columns. So, I change the name of columns from val_00 until val_11 and it works.